# Javascript object sorting based on another object key

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript objects:

```
var list = [];
list.push({'xid':'12345@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'6789@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'1357@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'2468@kvm.dooth.com'});

var recent = [];
recent.push({'12345@kvm.dooth.com':3});
recent.push({'1357@kvm.dooth.com':1});
recent.push({'2468@kvm.dooth.com':2});
```

I need to sort `list` object using `recent` object. I am expecting an output like:

```
[{
  'xid': '1357@kvm.dooth.com'
}, {
  'xid': '2468@kvm.dooth.com'
}, {
  'xid': '12345@kvm.dooth.com'
}, {
  'xid': '6789@kvm.dooth.com'
}]
```

Comment: What is the criteria of sorting and what you have tried so far ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort array by object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: recent object value  3,1,2. That keys are depend to list object

Comment: Please check your desired result! You said you wanted to sort `recent` not `list`! And why having two arrays that pretty much contain the same thing?

Comment: need to sort list object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create one object or hash table from `recent` array and then you can use `sort()` to sort by that object. First you need to sort by values that exists in `recent` from `list` or that are `!= undefined` and then by values in recent object.

```js
var list = [];
list.push({'xid':'12345@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push( {'xid':'6789@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push( {'xid':'1357@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'2468@kvm.dooth.com'});

var recent = [];
recent.push({'12345@kvm.dooth.com':3});
recent.push({'1357@kvm.dooth.com':1});
recent.push({'2468@kvm.dooth.com':2});

var hash = recent.reduce(function(r, e) {
  for(var i in e) r[i] = e[i]
  return r
}, {})

var result = list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return ((hash[b.xid] != undefined) - (hash[a.xid] != undefined)) || 
    (hash[a.xid] - hash[b.xid])
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: I need a modification, now varible recent is array of objects thats change to just anobject {'12345@kvm.dooth.com':3,'1357@kvm.dooth.com':1,'2468@kvm.dooth.com':2};

Answer (score 0):

```
const sortedList = list.sort((a, b) => {
  // The ids
  const aXid = a.xid
  const bXid = b.xid

  // The positions
  const [aPos] = recent.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty(aXid)).map(e => e[aXid])
  const [bPos] = recent.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty(bXid)).map(e => e[bXid])

  // Compare like usual numbers
  return (aPos || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) - (bPos || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var list = [];
list.push({'xid':'12345@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'6789@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'1357@kvm.dooth.com'});
list.push({'xid':'2468@kvm.dooth.com'});

var recent = [];
recent.push({'12345@kvm.dooth.com':3});
recent.push({'1357@kvm.dooth.com':1});
recent.push({'2468@kvm.dooth.com':2});

function sort(list, recent){
  list.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = getEmailValue(recent, a["xid"]);
    b = getEmailValue(recent, b["xid"]);
    return (a !== undefined) ? (a - b) : 1;
  });
}

function getEmailValue(recent, email) {
  var elem = recent.find(function (e) {
    return e[email] !== undefined;
  });

  return elem && elem[email];
}

sort(list, recent);
console.log(list);
```

`sort()` works by taking two elements from the array - `a` and `b`. It sorts them based on the return value of a compare function. If that function returns a positive number, `a` is put after `b`, if it's negative, `a` is before `b`, else they are unchanged.

In this:

```
return (a !== undefined) ? (a - b) : 1;
```

If `a` is `undefined` (`getEmailValue()` has returned nothing), `1` is returned to sort it in the back. In your example, emails with no value in `recent` are at the bottom of the list.

This:

```
return elem && elem[email];
```

Will return `elem[email]` if `elem` is not `undefined`, else it will return `undefined`. It's a way to prevent accessing the `email` property of something that is not an object. For more info, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

> Logical AND (&&) - expr1 && expr2 - Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Comment: Thanks for your reply